# MIgrate a NFT to IPFS after minting?

Tags: solidity, nft, ipfs, meta-data

Hi I would like to know if it is possible to migrate my NFT from a standard webserver to IPFS after minting it? I already generated and minted my NFTs and now I would like to call the basetokeURI and point everything to my IPFS metadata but is not working.

Comment: What do you mean with 'is not working'? Is the contract deployed? What's the contract address? An EIP-721 compliant wallet will call `tokenURI` to get the URI. Is that function returning a valid URI?

Answer (score 0):

Since the transaction is "written" on the blockchain you cannot update it. You would have to mint it again

Comment: But why if in my contract I can change the basetokenURI?

Comment: But what about https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87853/updating-erc-721-tokens-metadata-after-it-was-minted